# How to change the next-in-line cell according to previous cell in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

In the A column, there's "A" in A1, "B" in A2, "C" in A3, "D" in A4 and "E" in A5.
In the B column, there's "F" in B1, "G" in B2, "H" in B3, "I" in B4 and "J" in B5.
In D1, I have a dropdown of A1:A5.

Like this:

[image: 1]

I wish that E1 would show the matching B cell to the dropdown in D1.
So, for instance, if I put "A" in the dropdown, E1 would show "F", or if I put "C" in the dropdown, E1 would show "H".

Do anyone knows if this is possible in Google Sheets? If so, how?

I'm not familiar with Google Sheets or any excels-like programm, so I don't even know how to try anything, honestly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use VLOOKUP. It looks in the first column of the range and returns the value in the second one:

```
=VLOOKUP(D1,A:B,2,0)
```

[image]